# Block Gutenberg Editor manually by User Roles with a Filter with code

Tags: filters, user-roles

This *is* working perfectly for me but, is this an *acceptable WP* way to do it?  Just trying to check that based on user role that the Gutenberg Editor blocked from showing up, like when creating a post, or page.  I don't want to use a Plugin; that seems overkill,  and since the posts will be created with Advanced Custom Fields the Gutenberg editor does not need to show up and confuse people.

I'm asking because somewhere I read you should not use `wp_get_current_user` for something like this but since it's just a Filter, I thought it would be OK.

```php
$user = wp_get_current_user();
$allowed_roles = array('editor', 'author', 'contributor');
if (array_intersect($allowed_roles, $user->roles)) {
    add_filter('use_block_editor_for_post', '__return_false', 10);
}
```

Always trying to learn/improve, thank you looking!

Comment: `contributer` is misspelt, what's the reason for preventing editors/authors from being able to use the block editor, but using it for administrators? This will cause problems when editors open posts that have been modified using the block editor which then strips out the block markup. Some blocks are only saved as the block markup HTML comments and would be removed entirely. Have you looked at ACF blocks or the support ACF offers for the block editor?

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the spelling mistake!  I fixed it!  The pages are made up with ACF layouts so don't want Gutenberg to show up; also there won't be any posts made with the Block Editor...

Comment: @TomJNowell ... or are you saying that if in the future we decide to not use the post template made with ACF that everything will get stripped out... is that what you mean?

Comment: I mean if you write things in the block editor, the HTML is wrapped in HTML comments. The classic editor is unaware of this and can strip them out. Since your filter only applies to editors/authors/contributors, an Admin opening the post will launch the block editor make changes, then have all the block HTML stripped out when an editor or author opens it in the classic editor and saves

Comment: Note that ACF may have similar behaviour differences between the block editor and the classic editor too. If you're going to force the classic editor force it for everybody, why restrict it to specific roles. Keep in mind the classic editor is legacy and not receiving new features, even ACF may not be fully present. Keep in mind that 3rd party plugins are offtopic here so you can't ask about ACF, you would need to ask that in an ACF community

Comment: @TomJNowell  ok so no they are not using the Classic Editor nor Gutenberg.  They will be using a custom page template made from ACF layout fields :)  I guess I'm not explaining it very well.  They only need access to these ACF fields to build their own post.  That's why the Gutenberg editor does not need to be in there.  They won't need either editor.

Comment: my point is, why restrict to just specific roles when you can restrict all roles and never worry about the problem in the first place? That would be the most compatible option and reduce your code to a single line. You've explained why you want to disable the block editor, but glossed over the specific roles part

Comment: @TomJNowell ** so you make a good point except it might be ME adding some posts, and doing editing in there too, so I didn't want my admin role to be restricted.  My question what more about if my code was ok; with that being said I have been rethinking it anyway so your help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This is working perfectly for me but, is this an acceptable WP way to do it?

If it works and you didn't modify core or internal WP private objects then the way you did it is fine.

> I'm asking because somewhere I read you should not use wp_get_current_user for something like this but since it's just a Filter, I thought it would be OK.

That's not what you did though, and it's likely a misinterpretation. The problem with `wp_get_current_user` is that if you call it too early it might not work.

> Just trying to check that based on user role that the Gutenberg Editor blocked from showing up, like when creating a post, or page.

This is likely the issue though, it would be better to prevent all roles or no roles for maximum compatibility, especially since the editor is disabled conditionally, and plugins are expected to be written with the assumption of the block editor going forwards.

While there are issues with users opening posts edited with the block editor in the classic editor erasing HTML comments in the post content, you would need to ask in an ACF community if ACF has similar issues.

There is also the problem of new roles being added that would not be accounted for by the code. It would be better to have a list of roles that can access the block editor than a list of roles that can't.

However, I see no reason not to whittle down the code to just this:

```php
add_filter( 'use_block_editor_for_post', '__return_false' );
```

It would be more compatible, simpler, faster, and can be used in more places and earlier hooks.

Comment: Ok this is exactly the type of answer I was looking for... thank you!!  I especially like your idea of this:  "It would be better to have a list of roles that can access the block editor than a list of roles that can't."

Comment: note that the same ethos also applies to `WP_Query` and performance, always be asking for what you want, not what you don't want. Exclusions are expensive!